# Travis CI - Enabling repository build via API

Tags: travis-ci, travis-ci-cli

I can't find how to enable a repository to build in Travis CI through the API in the docs. It seems flicking the switch is a manual step, is that correct?

Specifically can we **flick the switch** shown in the image below programmatically? [image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this @ChucK?

Comment: @quine we used the hooks API with the GitHub repository ID as described in Fabio's accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The end-point for this is kind of misleading and also it takes more than one step to achieve this:

1. Force a synchronization just to make sure the repo will be there

   - Use [users/sync](https://docs.travis-ci.com/api#users) end-point
2. Obtain the repository ID (yes, you must have it)

   - Use [repos/repo.slug](https://docs.travis-ci.com/api#repositories) end-point
3. Flick the switch

   - Use [hooks/repo.id](https://docs.travis-ci.com/api#hooks) end-point

If you are working with Python you can use [TravisPy](https://github.com/menegazzo/travispy) to achieve this.

```
from travispy import TravisPy

travis = TravisPy.github_auth('github token')
repo = travis.repo('menegazzo/travispy')
repo.enable() # Switch is now on
repo.disable() # Switch is now off
```